# How to POST to NetSuite custom record from external site?

Tags: rest, xmlhttprequest, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to integrate a very small custom web application with NetSuite. I want a custom record to be created in NetSuite whenever a user clicks a button in my web application.

I have written a RESTlet that works with the REST API Testing chrome extension.  I have successfully created records through that chrome extension.

However, when I try to POST from my web application, I get this error:

> "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 401."

How can I POST to NetSuite with a RESTlet from an external site?  Should I even be using a RESTlet or is there a better way?

Comment: That's your browser and its CORS setting

If using chrome ( you should be ;) ) on Windows, create a shortcut with the following flags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RESTlets are meant more as a system to system technology. They require authentication and if you are doing that from a public app your credentials will be compromised.

Netsuite doesn't allow you to set a CORS header so your cross domain integration needs to be via a publicly available suitelet and JSONP.

Since JSONP makes use of get requests you need to make sure your url params end up less than about 2k characters. That's not a standard limit so ymmv

patterns I often use:
Client code:

```
var url = "public suitelet url from deployment screen";
    var params = {
        mode: 'neworder',
        //simple name/value data
    };
    $.ajax({
            url: url+"&"+ $.param(params) +"&jsoncallback=?",
            cache:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(jResp){
                if(!jResp.success){
                    if(jResp.message) alert(jResp.message);
                    return;
                }
                // act on the results
            }
    });
```

A library function in the suitelet source file.

```
function _sendJSResponse(request, response, respObject){
    response.setContentType('JAVASCRIPT');
    //response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    var callbackFcn = request.getParameter("jsoncallback")  || request.getParameter('callback');
    if(callbackFcn){
        response.writeLine( callbackFcn + "(" + JSON.stringify(respObject) + ");");
    }else response.writeLine( JSON.stringify(respObject) );
}
```

and then a Suitelet function

```
function service(request, response){
    ... do some work and generate a response
    var returnObj = {
        success:true,
        message: '',
        result:result
    };

    _sendJSResponse(request, response, returnObj);
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how can I create a custom record with an externally available Suitelet?  Aren't the APIs limited?  I don't see nlapiCreateRecord in this list:  See SuiteAnswers article 10354

Comment: I have done just about everything possible with externally available Suitelets. You can do anything server side that can be done within your 1000 unit governance limit. 
Make the role for the suitelet Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

That's your browser and its CORS setting

If using chrome ( you should be ;) ) on Windows, create a chrome shortcut with the following flags

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

Then, kill/restart ALL INSTANCES of chrome in the Task Manager and try your requests again

Otherwise google "disable CORS on MY_BROWSER"